# variable declared in app component giving build error

Tags: angular, build-error

Getting

> ERROR in src\app\app.component.html(2,13): : Property 'showHead' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

**App-Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public showHead : boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // on route change to '/login', set the variable showHead to false
    router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (event['url'] == '/login') {
          this.showHead = false;
        } else {
          this.showHead = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**app-component.html**

```
<div class="theme-light">
    <header *ngIf="showHead"></header>
    <app-menubar *ngIf="showHead"></app-menubar>
    <div class="appbody">            
       <router-outlet></router-outlet> 

    </div>
    <footer *ngIf="showHead"></footer>
</div>
```

**Angular CLI : 1.6.6
Angular: 5.2.10**

Comment: Can you make a related stackblltz or fiddle? I can't reproduce your problem on [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvbupk). Consider reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Getting Error only on using ng build --aot=true. ng serve and application working as expected.

Comment: Not seeing any issues in the code. public variable should be available by default in templates.

Comment: @Suresh, Yes correct its working in application fine, but creating issue inbuild.

Comment: any variable created in app component creating same issue.

Comment: we are also following the same in our project , its working fine. might be related to tsconfig/tslint